# How to integrate push notification code into my existing Android app from parse.com?

Tags: java, android, parsing, push-notification

I have just checkout http://www.parse.com and it gives great option to send push notification to android app. I have tried its sample push notification code and it works like a charm.

But I have no idea how will I integrate it in my existing Android app code.
I am a newbie. I have looked for examples over internet but could not find out how to integrate it in existing app code.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a5FIwGaJTxc

Comment: Hello Shivam, I am asking you about how to integrate this sample notification app given by parse.com into my existing app.  The link does not help :(

Comment: why not ? what's the problem?

Comment: As i have mentoined... I have already tried the sample android push notification program given by parse and it works fine. But the problem is i have no idea how to integrate this program into my existing android wallpaper app. Can you please help

Comment: No! The video does it. I might be able to help if you show us what you've tried and what problems you're facing.

Comment: Shivam i have seen it, its a 2 min video and simply teaches how how to run the sample push notifications android app given by parse.

Comment: I have an android  Wallpaper app and I wish to put push notificiations into this. But i have no idea how to put

Comment: @AmirAslam  u done ?